# How to restrict Mac OSx application to launch for only few OSx versions

Tags: macos

Is there any way we can restrict Mac OSx application to launch for only few versions? One method I found is by tagging LSMinimumSystemVersion tag in the plist. But here we can mention only the minimum version.

But I am in need of some settings where I can mention the OS version range, so that my Mac application should launch only with those versions.

For eg: Mac OSx application should launch only for 10.6, 107 and 10.8 and it should not work for 10.9 and above.

Your suggestions and support is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to enforce this your in your app logic (in the app delegate, for example):

```
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {

    unsigned kernelMajor, kernelMinor, kernelBugfix;
    unsigned osMajor, osMinor, osBugfix;
    char osrelease[256];
    size_t len = sizeof(osrelease);

    sysctlbyname("kern.osrelease", osrelease, &len, NULL, 0);

    if (sscanf(osrelease, "%u.%u.%u", &kernelMajor, &kernelMinor, &kernelBugfix) != 3) {
        if (sscanf(osrelease, "%u.%u", &kernelMajor, &kernelMinor) != 2) {
            // Throw exception here
        }
        kernelBugfix = 0;
    }

    // If kernel version = x.y.z
    // then OSX version = 10.(x-4).y
    osMajor = 10;
    osMinor = kernelMajor - 4;
    osBugfix = kernelMinor;

    if (osMinor >= 9) {
        // complain and exit
    }

}
```

(note that this method of getting the O/S version **is** supported under 10.8+, unlike the, now deprecated, `Gestalt()` method).